# Error when I Update Module List in OpenERP

Tags: magento, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to update my modulo list using the Update Module List menu item, but I get the follwing error:

```
OpenERP Server Error

Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 204, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1132, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(req, model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1120, in _call_kw
    return getattr(req.session.model(model), method)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 42, in proxy
    result = self.proxy.execute_kw(self.session._db, self.session._uid, self.session._password, self.model, method, args, kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 30, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 103, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.ustr(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/netsvc.py", line 296, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 190, in execute_kw
    return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 132, in wrapper
    return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 199, in execute
    res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 187, in execute_cr
    return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_module_update.py", line 42, in update_module
    update, add = module_obj.update_list(cr, uid,)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 617, in update_list
    handler.load_addons()
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 580, in load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/module.py", line 133, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/magento_integration-develop/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    import magento_
  File "/opt/bitnami/apps/openerp/lib/openerp-7.0_20140330_231328-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/magento_integration-develop/magento_.py", line 17, in <module>
    import magento
ImportError: No module named magento
```

I am trying to install a Magento OpenERP connector, but in order to to that I must locate it in the Installed Module list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file magento_.py, and see whether the class has been called.And if it has been called correctly check whether it has been correctly specified in the import line in your **init**.py file.